# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file <FILE> failed. A database with the same name exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the ASPNETDB.MDF database in the App_Data folder of my project.

I'm getting an error when I try to add a user:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(viewModel.Username, viewModel.Password, viewModel.Contact.Email,
                                            viewModel.SecurityQuestion, viewModel.SecurityAnswer, true, out createStatus);
```

The error is:

**An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Steven\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.WebUI\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.**

My web.config has this connection string and membership info:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ASPNETDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDB" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDB" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I have a feeling my connection string is wrong, but I really have no idea.

Comment: I did everything from this guide http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980 but no chance and finally attach it to server

Answer (score 1):

For starters will you please give this connection string a try?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ASPNETDB" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am also curious to know are you able to access the database at all from your application.  From your error, I would assume no.

Answer (score 1):

- While directory permissions, create new user "network service" and configure permissions
- Replace |Data directory| to "C:\inetpub\wwroot..."

It is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Running VisualStudio as Administrator solves this problem during development.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the application pool for the Site in IIS Manager to ASP.NET v4.0 solved the issue for me.

Comment: I doubt he's using IIS with the path of his project.